# Render Maquette without the Projector

Tags: javascript, svg, typescript, virtual-dom, maquette

I want to use Maquette as a basic hyperscript language. Consequently, I don't want to use the `maquette.projector`. However, I'm having a hard time getting any of the `maquette.dom` functions to work.

```js
var h = maquette.h;
var dom = maquette.dom;
var svg = h('div.sweet', [
  h('svg', [
    h('circle', { cx: '2cm', cy: '2cm', r: '4cm', fill: 'red' }),
  ])
]);

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  console.log(svg);
  var root = dom.create(svg).domNode;
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/maquette/2.4.1/maquette.min.js"></script>
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is `dom.create` not rendering anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice to see that you have found another usecase without the projector. The `dom.create` method only creates the DOM nodes, but it does not append them anywhere in the document. You can use `document.body.appendChild(root)` or use `dom.append(document.body, svg)`.